# SharePoint Search REST API with bearer token returns wrong number of items

Tags: rest, sharepoint, bearer-token

I have an EXTREMELY strange issue with the search.
I am doing a query by using a GET on 
`https://sonar-sandbox.gredspdev.loc/_api/search/query?querytext='DMSSonarDocId:5042aa1f-b3a4-4577-8e21-8a47ca27c243 OR DMSSonarDocId:1401144b-bd3d-429a-a386-5061ecc714e1'&sourceid='a0f4d450-e701-4f2a-888a-8d871002752d'&trimduplicates=false&rankingmodelid='05289DBE-73E9-4665-BF69-EE68274176EB'&rowlimit=9000&enablestemming=false&enablesorting=false&selectproperties='DMSSonarDocId,<...>`'

I am authenticating using a bearer token generated for my user. This query returns 7 items. Then I am executing THE SAME URL in my browser with my user (NTLM) and it returns 10 items. That is not all. I generate the token for my user one more time. Paste it to the previous GET request with a bearer token and it returns 10 items... I am waiting few seconds, lets say 30... GET one more time and I have 7 items returned (always the same)! And this is 100% replicable. After another GET from the browser and regeneration of the token 10 items, after some time on the same token 7 items....

Update. I have found difference in logs in ULS:
When working correct:

```
Context has no SMTP/UPN claims. IdentityContext: '{"nameid":"s-1-5-21-2843295230-2675739751-2774624307-1482","nii":"urn:office:idp:activedirectory","upn":"kowalj@spdev.loc","userId":"0#.w|spdev\\kowalj","appliesTo":"https:\/\/sonar-sandbox.spdev.loc\/"}'
```

When not working correct:

```
Context has no SMTP/UPN claims. IdentityContext: '{"nameid":"s-1-5-21-2843295230-2675739751-2774624307-1482","nii":"urn:office:idp:activedirectory","upn":"spdev\\kowalj","userId":"0#.w|spdev\\kowalj","appliesTo":"https:\/\/sonar-sandbox.spdev.loc\/"}'
```

ANOTHER FINDINGS:
Missing items are those which are assigned to me directly - not through group resolved by our custom claims provider - yes, we have a custom claims provider which worked ok for a long time (we were using only NTLM authorization).
We are sending those claims:

```
new Claim[]
{
    new Claim("nameid", sid),
    new Claim("nii", Constants.Auth.Token.IdentityIssuer)
};
```

**ANOTHER FINDINGS:**
When everything work correctly, executing this code in the SP farm solution in some REST proxy: `((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User?.Identity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType.EqualsIgnoreCase(ClaimTypes.Upn))` returns upn.
When the search is not working, the same code returns null... And as I said, I can refresh the page and at the beginning the upn is there and after some time it is not...

Comment: what are the extra items each time?

Comment: Those are normal items (office documents as other). And this is correct that they appear. The problem is that they disappear.

Comment: After some investigation - missing items are those which are assigned to me directly (permissions set directly to my user - not by the group etc.). We are using custom claims provider but it was working ok when we were using NTLM. It should be ok now as groups are resolved ok. Only direct assignments are not working.

Comment: In my opinion, you have been too clever with rights, make sure that the system account that is configured in the search service has access to all libraries and lists at your request.

Comment: But the search is working fine when we are using just SharePoint. The problem arise when we authenticate by the full trust AddIn and REST call. And additionally this is working fine too few seconds after using SharePoint (in the browser by using NTLM - for example entering the main page) as this user. After that our code with authentication through the AddIn and using REST works. After few seconds it stops to work properly and returns only some items (those to which the user has permission through groups etc and not directly - so those calculated by our claims provider only)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work around. Not very good but I do not see any other option for now.
We have started Claims to Windows Token Service and if user does some requests to our app, we do (from time to time) requests to our custom proxy placed in the SharePoint farm solution to simulate using SharePoint by that user by using normal windows authentication:

```
public void RefreshUpn()
{
    WindowsImpersonationContext _wic = null;
    try
    {
        string login = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        login = login.Substring(login.LastIndexOf('|') + 1);
        string[] loginParts = login.Split('\\');
        string loginForUpnLogon = Culture.Invariant($"{loginParts[1]}@{loginParts[0]}");
        WindowsIdentity wi = S4UClient.UpnLogon(loginForUpnLogon);

        if(wi == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(Culture.Invariant($"Could not impersonate user '{HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name}'."));
        }

        _wic = wi.Impersonate();

        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            var requestUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
            wc.DownloadString(requestUrl.Scheme + "://" + requestUrl.Host + "/_api/web/currentuser");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _wic?.Undo();
    }
}
```

After such request, SharePoint responses to us correctly for around 150 seconds.

Comment: After deploying the solution to a different environment with a different domain the fix is not working... so to sum up - on my VM everything is working ok without a fix, on second env we need to apply this fix/workaround and on third env even this fix is not helping.... ehh...